# Remove "/usr/bin/sensors" from output of Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

So I have this piece of code:

```sh
if type -P sensors 2>/dev/null; then
  returnString=`sensors`
  #amd
  if [[ "${returnString/"k10"}" != "${returnString}" ]] ; then
    $SENSORS | grep Tdie | $CUT -d ' ' -f 10 | { echo "{"; cat; echo "}"; } | tr -d '\n'
  #intel
  elif [[ "${returnString/"core"}" != "${returnString}" ]] ; then
    fromcore=${returnString##*"coretemp"}
    $ECHO ${fromcore##*Physical}  | $CUT -d ' ' -f 3 | $CUT -c 2-5 | _parseAndPrint
  fi
else
  $ECHO "[]" | _parseAndPrint
fi
```

Its output is:

```
/usr/bin/sensors
{+31.9°C}
```

But the desired output is:

```
{+31.9°C}
```

Sensors output:

```
/usr/bin/sensors
nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +33.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +74.8°C)
                       (crit = +79.8°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Vcore:         1.12 V  
Vsoc:        888.00 mV 
Tctl:         +31.1°C  
Tdie:         +31.1°C  
Icore:         8.00 A  
Isoc:          5.00 A
```

I would really prefer to leave `if type -P sensors 2>/dev/null; then` in place, so it can still detect if it is Intel or AMD.

The line is run in a script file, which can be found [here](https://github.com/chibbi/ComputerDashboard/blob/4b4256b08349d2ca9accffc8405d4d82b14f4078/linux_json_api.sh#L134).

Comment: If you show us what comes out of a "naked" `sensors` run, we can give you a much better way - most text processing pipelines can usually be replaced with a single `awk`. That includes whether or not multiple temperatures may appear.

Comment: Is "/usr/bin/sensors" being printed to stdout or to stderr? Does `sensors 2>/dev/null | ...` suppress it?

Comment: Good point, @Gordon, the fact it's not surrounded by braces probably means it's on stderr.

Comment: ```sensors 2>/dev/null``` = ```sensors 2>/dev/null | grep Tdie | $CUT -d ' ' -f 10 | { echo "{"; cat; echo "}"; } | tr -d '\n'```, has the same output as without "2>/dev/null"

Comment: jeah so i was kinda dumb and didn't realise, that 3 lines before "sensors 2>/dev/null" is already called, sadly i am still not really able to remove "/usr/bin/sensors"

Comment: Then one call of `sensors` is probably missing the `2> /dev/null`. You can automatically add it by [introducing a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65535354/6770384).

Comment: You should do it with either `awk` or `python`.

Comment: I won't do it with python, and awk i put that in i think (i just didn't change the question again)

Comment: @chipcoint : Please don't forget to accept an answer, in case it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just not the smartest right now, should've looked at the rest of the Code and should sleep xD.  I could just remove the check,that checks if "sensors" is accessible (at least i think that is what it was used for).
so from

```
      if type -P sensors 2>/dev/null; then
        returnString=`sensors`
        #amd
        if [[ "${returnString/"k10"}" != "${returnString}" ]] ; then
          sensors | grep Tdie | $CUT -d ' ' -f 10 | { echo "{"; cat; echo "}"; } | tr -d '\n'
        #intel
        elif [[ "${returnString/"core"}" != "${returnString}" ]] ; then
          fromcore=${returnString##*"coretemp"}
          $ECHO ${fromcore##*Physical}  | $CUT -d ' ' -f 3 | $CUT -c 2-5 | _parseAndPrint
        fi
      else
        $ECHO "[]" | _parseAndPrint
      fi
```

I made

```
        returnString=`sensors`
        #amd
        if [[ "${returnString/"k10"}" != "${returnString}" ]] ; then
          sensors | sed -nE 's/^Tdie: *([^ ]*)/{\1}/p'
        #intel
        elif [[ "${returnString/"core"}" != "${returnString}" ]] ; then
          fromcore=${returnString##*"coretemp"}
          $ECHO ${fromcore##*Physical}  | $CUT -d ' ' -f 3 | $CUT -c 2-5 | _parseAndPrint
        fi
```

Comment: That ``returnString=`sensors` `` looks like it is causing the message. Replace it by `returnString=$(sensors 2> /dev/null)`.

Comment: ```      if type -P sensors 2>/dev/null; then
        returnString=$(sensors 2> /dev/null)
        #amd
        if [[ "${returnString/"k10"}" != "${returnString}" ]] ; then
          $(sensors 2> /dev/null) | grep Tdie | $CUT -d ' ' -f 10 | { echo "{"; cat; echo "}"; } | tr -d '\n'
        #intel``` like that ? (if yes it didn't work xD)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `type` command. You only need the exit status of this command, but it writes in your case the path of the sensor command to stdout. You should redirect its stdout to /dev/null.